# android phone what is the localhost?

Tags: android, client-server, localhost

I created 2 different android apps on my phone. One is a client and the other one is the server. I am planning to send a message from the client to the server using the same phone. Can I do that?

At the client side I did add the ip: 10.0.2.2 but when the server is up no message is arriving. Why? What is the localhost of an android phone?

Need some help. Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: I am sending a UDP packet. On the client side I have message UDP Blocked? Why?

Comment: i think since you are using two apps for send and recieve the _android sandbox_ is the reson you dont get the data in other app. the doc says **The Android Application Sandbox, which isolates your app data and code execution from other apps.**

Comment: you can create a file and store it in a place inside sd card, write the file and use it from other app to read it.  for more info http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

Comment: You did try 127.0.0.1 (which is _the_ ip of localhost), didn't you? And are the Android permissions for internet ok?

Comment: I did try 10.0.2.2 and I do have android permissions. The client is sending some udp packets. I am trying to catch those udp packets on the server side. Server is running on port x and client is sending udp packet on that port x and ip 10.0.2.2

Comment: I have a while(true) on the server side. Still when client is sending packets I get udp blocked and no message on server side:(